# rails group records by dates of created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a model that I want to retrieve records and group them by dates of the created_at field. But created_at is a datetime field, and I am only interested in the date part. So I am looking for something like a 2D array, first layer would a hash with date string as the key, second layer would be arrays with records. How should I do it?

```
{
"9/28/2012" => [record, record, record],
"9/29/2012" => [record, record, record],
"9/30/2012" => [record, record, record]
}
```

At top of the above, how should I do it if I want the above arrange be applied to all records retrieved from this model?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ActiveRecord `group` method will do what you need.  In your case, the problem will be with using `created_at` which is a datetime, and your constraint to group by date. Since casting date-times to dates is database-specific, the code will need to be database-specific as well.

For MySql you can do:

```
Model.group("date(table_name.created_at)")
```

For SQLite you can do:

```
Model.group("strftime('%Y-%m-%d', table_name.created_at)")
```

And for PostgreSQL:

```
Model.group("table_name.created_at::date")
```

This code will unfortunately not be portable, but that may not matter to you.  If it does, you can always build a wrapper method that selects the correct conversion syntax based on your DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

On ActiveRecord you can do this:

```
2.6.4 :036 > User.group('created_at::date').count

   (5.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, created_at::date AS created_at_date FROM "users" GROUP BY created_at::date
 => {Sat, 27 Feb 2021=>5865
```

Comment: User was asking for a list of records grouped by date - not a count of records grouped by date 