# undefined method `group_by_day' error rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, chartkick

I have installed gem groupdate and gem chartkick and already restart my server. I'm enable to display the graph that sorted by group_by_day at my show.html.erb. I'm using postgresql database

show.html.erb

```
<%= @material.current_stock %>
<%= line_chart @material.group_by_day(:updated_at).sum(:current_stock) %>
```

controller/material_controller.rb

```
def show
   @material = Material.find(params[:id])
end
```

it's working fine when I declare using the class

```
<%= line_chart Material.group_by_day(:updated_at).sum(:current_stock) %>
```

but not when I replace Material with @material.

Comment: are you using `sqlite` DB?

Comment: @uzaif, I'm using postgresql

Comment: There is a little Gotch with `Groupdate Gem`. In order to fix this I have to convert `created_at` to respective time zone. For more info [My Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178726/rails-group-by-hour-of-the-day-for-created-at-column). And you have to call `group-by-day` on ActiveRecord class not on object.

Answer (score 0):

It should be work with Class method and array ,

controller/material_controller.rb

```
def show
   @material = Material.where(id:params[:id])
end
```

Change with this your controller method

Answer (score 0):

The group_by_day works for either a whole class or a group of objects, **there is no use to group a single @material object**.

For the whole class you can use,

`Material.group_by_day(:updated_at).sum(:current_stock)`

For group of materials,

```
@materials = Material.where('your logic')

@materials.group_by_day { |u| u.updated_at }.sum(:current_stock)
```

But if you want to group for a single object try,

```
@material = Material.where('your logic').first

@material.group_by_day { |u| u.updated_at }.sum(:current_stock)
```